# Core Data Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Why do I see error an in my project? In `fiolbl.text = profiless.name` after compile my app crash and give: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

```
   @IBOutlet weak var fiolbl: UILabel!
var profiless: Profile!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fiolbl.text = profiless.name
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line of the crash, and check the value of `profiless`. If it's `nil`, that's causing the crash.

Comment: Why ask for help twice? This is a Q&A site, just post your question and leave out the chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour))